# Remove first, and last pagination from the jquery data table

Tags: jquery, datatable

I'm currently using [jQuery Datatable](http://datatables.net). I also use jquery ui to provide good theme. However, I want to disable (hide) the `first` and `last` button of the pagination from the table by using a bit customization on jquery library.
[image]

The problem is that the customization has only 2 methods: `full_numbers` and `two_button`.

So how can I get the pagination without the `first` and last `button`?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write your own javascript to hide/remove the elements.

`$(".first.paginate_button, .last.paginate_button").hide();`

Comment: In order to get rid of it, I use `$(".first.paginate_button, .last.paginate_button").remove();` to remove those objects. However, thanks so much for great help.

Answer (score 16):

You have 4 options:

- `simple` - 'Previous' and 'Next' buttons only
- `simple_numbers` - 'Previous' and 'Next' buttons, plus page numbers
- `full` - 'First', 'Previous', 'Next' and 'Last' buttons
- `full_numbers` - 'First', 'Previous', 'Next' and 'Last' buttons, plus page numbers

So in your case :

```
$("#youridtable").dataTable(
{
  "pagingType": "simple_numbers"
});
```

src: http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html

Comment: Thanks for explanation..great answer @jteks

Answer (score 1):

You can always use css

```
.dataTables_paginate .last{display:none;}
```

Answer (score 1):

We do not need to use CSS. Just hack into sFirst and sLast options of Datatable:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "oLanguage": {
      "oPaginate": {
        "sFirst": "",
        "sLast": ""
      }
   }
  });
});
```

Reference: http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/i18n